# iPod Nano 6G on Linux

Tags: linux, fedora, apple

I see that Apple no longer supports `libgpod` for the iPhone4/iPod Touch 4 and Nano 6G. I see also that the system of databases for those new device has to be the same.

I found many videos where you can see `libimobiledevice` works well with iPhone but none about the "new" Nano 6G and I couldn't get it to work - unlike my old Nano 1G that does.

It's normal that the Nano 6G doesn't work?

Is there a way, including with commercial programs, to sync my iPod Nano 6G under Linux (without dualboot or VM)?

I'm running Fedora 16 x64.

Answer (score 1):

Get Spotify (the program, whether or not you actually use the streaming music is up to you).

Yes, I know I sound like a corporate sock. It does sync the 6G, though, and it works almost flawlessly for that.